# Prolog Compiler for .Net

Tags: .net, prolog

Can anyone recommend a Prolog compiler for .Net.

The ones that I have been able to find searching the net, do not appear to have been updated for several years.

Thanks

Shiraz

Comment: I'm not sure what the programming language's "paradigm" has to do with the back-end it's compiled to.  Does the Prolog paradigm fit any better with x86/ppc/sparc/alpha/mips?  :-)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - Prolog is awesome at solving many problems that are extremely difficult to code in c#. I've often wanted to mix prolog into c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhm, I googled for "Prolog.NET" [and found this](http://prolog.hodroj.net/) (1st result btw)

> Prolog.NET is a full featured Prolog
>   programming environment for the .NET
>   Framework. It includes an enhanced
>   compiler with language extensions and
>   a code generator targeting Microsoft's
>   Intermediate Language (MSIL) and
>   integration with Visual Studio .NET
>   Integrated development environment.

Comment: Thanks, I found that one, but it is version 0.2 from 2006. Was just wondering if something more recent was available.

Comment: Then you should have put that reference in the question.

Comment: He said in the question that he searched for prolog compilers and found only abandoned projects. What's the point of giving him a link to another abandoned project?

Comment: Prolog.NET is a university student's capstone project, so it's not likely to get updated.  It's either good or it isn't, but having a date of 2006 on it doesn't mean that it's bad software.  Why don't you try it, and see if it works for you?

Answer (score 3):

On this article they recommend [P#](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/stg/research/Psharp/) and XSB: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/PrologNET.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have used [C#Prolog](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cs-prolog/) by John Pool

The source code is available and in C#. There are also several PDF articles in the download. Nice if you want to dig into the internals.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [XProlog](https://github.com/bzaar/prolog).  It is extremely lightweight and it offers a compiler and a runtime DLL (30K in size).  Full source code is available on GitHub that is exhaustively unit-tested.  Although it is currently missing some basic Prolog features like lists, it does allow for building functional programs and even supports definite clause grammars.  The XProlog compiler is written in XProlog and it compiles itself.

Disclaimer: I am the author of XProlog.  It took me 4 months to write it and it was written for a task I then had at hand and now it is just sitting there on GitHub waiting for other great tasks.  Hope you find it useful:

- [XProlog](https://github.com/bzaar/prolog)

Answer (score -1):

If you dont find you maybe need this tool Microsoft  Oslo (Codename). This is a software for can create DSL's and work perfectly for develop a diagram syntax for compilers.

Check this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Oslo_MGrammar.aspx?display=PrintAll