# Prolog with .NET

Tags: .net, prolog, clr

[There's already a question like this one but she's 4 years old and my question is kind of  "time related"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053425/prolog-compiler-for-net).

I need to implement some logic with prolog and call it from a CLR based application (mainly C# from Windows and Mono and also Scala from Windows) to take advantage of some Prolog features. The problem is, I can't found maintained "Prolog.NET" compiler...

- [Prolog.NET](http://prolog.hodroj.net/) looks like 2 years old.
- [P#](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/stg/research/Psharp/screenshots/) looks like 9 years old
- The other [Prolog.NET](http://prolog.codeplex.com/) looks like 3 years old

So do you have any still maintained Prolog compiler ? Or, by experience, do you think one of the one above are enough stable and enough secure to use them even without support ?

Comment: maybe you find more information on stackoverflow.com, [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053425/prolog-compiler-for-net

Comment: This is exactly the previous question I was talking to. This Q/A is 4 years old and the mentionned compiler are the same I mention. But thx anyway :)

Comment: What really sucks, is when Lambdas and LINQ was added to .Net, it was demonstrated by writing Prolog code in .Net - no interpreter or  DLL or any such, pure native Prolog in you c# file. I've searched and searched and never found it since.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one, C# Prolog, looks to be in development (latest release tagged as June 2013). Whether it's any good or not (or better than the other ones), I've got no idea.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cs-prolog/

Also, [Amzi Prolog](http://www.amzi.com/) has a binding for .Net:

http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/ls/lsadotnet.htm

And here's a CLR binding to integrate SWI-Prolog into the .Net world:

http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/Generated/Index.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No answer yet, so I can suggest a 'midway' solution: attach a bit of managed C++ to your project, as a shared DLL, exposing .Net properties/methods, and interact Prolog side by means of [C++ interface](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/pl2cpp.html) - handy and powerful (exceptions, type validation, environment allocation control, etc).